# Socket client-server соединение между пк и андроид

Tags: c#, android, сокет, клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте, за неимением опыта и знаний не могу разобраться в проблеме, надеюсь на помощь. У меня на ПК написан простой socket server на C#

```
        try
        {
            IPAddress localAddress = IPAddress.Parse("10.152.8.26");

            Socket listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            IPEndPoint ipEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(localAddress, 5555);

            listenSocket.Bind(ipEndpoint);

            listenSocket.Listen(1);

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server wait {0}", ipEndpoint);

                Socket handler = listenSocket.Accept();

                Console.WriteLine("Connect with {0}", handler.RemoteEndPoint);

                Console.WriteLine("Send message..");
                handler.Send(encoding.GetBytes("I'm wait"));

                Console.WriteLine("Close connect");
                handler.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

И socket client на android

```
public class ClientActivity extends Activity {

EditText textOut;
TextView textIn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client);

    textOut = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button buttonSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    textIn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(buttonSendOnClickListener);
}

 Button.OnClickListener buttonSendOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
   //@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Socket socket = null;
     DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
     DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

     try {
      socket = new Socket("10.152.8.26", 5555);
      dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
      dataOutputStream.writeUTF(textOut.getText().toString());

      String readUTF = dataInputStream.readUTF();

      textIn.setText(readUTF);

     } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     } 
     finally{
       try {
           if (socket != null){

        socket.close();
        } 
           if (dataOutputStream != null){

               dataOutputStream.close();
            } 
           if (dataInputStream != null){

               dataInputStream.close();
            } 
       }
           catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }

      if (dataOutputStream != null){
       try {
        dataOutputStream.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }

      if (dataInputStream != null){
       try {
        dataInputStream.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }

    }

    }
    ;}
```

Я очень плохо в этом разбираюсь, весь код нагуглил. Если с андроида в браузере вводить адрес и порт, сервер видит коннект. А через приложение на телефоне ничего не проиходит. Помогите пожалуйста советом, что не так?

Comment: что в логе? Права на интернет в манифесте добавил?

Comment: где и какой лог? права в манифесте добавил, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE, INTERNET, CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE

Comment: трудно так писать когда весь код нагуглен. Без лога действительно будет тяжко вам подсказать что-то полезное. Мой вариант что у вас например вот это http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Comment: спасибо, видимо нужно попробовать использовать AsyncTask

Comment: @Bigaloy если код не работает, то с AsyncTask уж подавно не заработает + заработаете себе гемор с отладкой с тредами... логи понаставьте хотя бы и изучите что такое LogCat

Comment: про LogCat кстати, я приложение тестил сразу на телефоне (наверно тупо, но все же), переделаю под localhost, попробую на эмуляторе

Comment: для работы с нэтом полюбому надо юзать потоки..

Comment: После отладки пожалуйста, но если не работает код то рановато переходить к потокам - тем более что у меня внутренняя уверенность что автор не подозревает походу что AsyncTask это и есть потоки :)

Comment: уверенность вас не подводит))) но спасибо вам за советы, буду дальше разбираться, рановато мне еще гуру беспокоить))))